# Query to find maximum in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to find maximum score of user id with the maximum quiz score in a category.

My Model:

```
class QuizCat(models.Model):

    cid = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Quiz(models.Model):

    Qid = models.IntegerField()
    cat_id = models.ForeignKey(QuizCat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class UserDetails(models.Model):

    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    Qid = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried:

```
    category_id = request.GET.get('category_id')
    result = UserDetails.objects.all().values('user_id').annotate(score=Sum('score')).filter(Qid__cat_id=category_id)
```

But the above did  not work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Sum, use [**`Max`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet):

```
result = UserDetails.objects.filter(Qid__cat_id=category_id).values('user_id').annotate(score=Max('score'))
```